# Jackson/YAML: Parse key-value into class

Tags: java, jackson, yaml, jackson2

I my input yaml file, I have the following:

```
services:
  postgresql:
    image: "postgres:10"
  redis:
    image: "redis:4"
```

It's easy to parse `services` field into a `Map<String, Service>`:

```
public class DockerCompose {
    public static class Service {
        private String image;
    }

    private Map<String, Service> services;
}
```

I would like to parse the `services` field in a `List<Service>` with the name in the field `name` in `Service` as following:

```
public class DockerCompose {
    public static class Service {
        private String name;
        private String image;
    }

    private List<Service> services;
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is add custom setter for deserialization and getter for serialization.

```
public static class DockerCompose {

    public static class Service {
        @JsonIgnore // for serialization
        private String name;
        private String image;
    }

    @JsonProperty("services") // for derserialization
    public void setServicesMap(Map<String, Service> servicesMap){
        for (Map.Entry<String, Service> entry  :servicesMap.entrySet()) {
            entry.getValue().name = entry.getKey();
            services.add(entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    @JsonProperty("services") // for serialization
    public Map<String, Service> getServicesMap() {
        Map<String, Service> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(Service s: services)
            map.put(s.getName(), s);
        return map;
    }

    @JsonIgnore // for serialization
    private List<Service> services = new ArrayList<>();
}
```